# Massaging a mongoid habtm with a string for a class

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra, mongoid, eval

I started off with https://gist.github.com/scttnlsn/1295485 as a basis to make a restful sinatra app. I'm having difficulty, though, managing HaBTM relationships for paths such as

`delete '/:objecttype/:objid/:habtm_type/:habtm_id'`

I already have the objecttype thanks to the map (as per that gist), and pulling the right object from the db with the id is straightfoward.  However, getting the other side of the habtm and calling the appropriate method on objecttype to delete the relationship involves turning a handful of strings into the appropriate objects and methods.

I came up with a solution, but it uses eval. I'm aware that using eval is evil and doing so will rot my very soul. Is there a better way to handle this, or should I put in some safeguards to protect the code and call it a day?

Here's a working, self contained, sinatra-free example to show how I'm doing the eval:

```
require 'mongoid'
require 'pp'

def go
  seed

  frank = Person.find_by(name:"Frank")
  apt = Appointment.find_by(name:"Arbor day")

  pp frank
  really_a_sinatra_route(frank.id, "appointments", apt.id)
  frank.reload
  pp frank
end

def really_a_sinatra_route(id, rel_type,rel_id)
  # I use "model" in the actual app, but hardwired a person here to 
  # make a simpler example

  person  = Person.find_by(id: id)
  person.deassociate(rel_type,rel_id)
end

class Base
  def deassociate(relationship,did)
    objname = associations[relationship].class_name

    # Here's the real question... this scares me as dangerous. Is there 
    # a safer way to do this?
    obj = eval "#{objname}.find(did)"
    eval "#{relationship}.delete(obj)"
  end
end

class Person < Base
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :appointments

end

class Appointment < Base
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
end

def seed
  Mongoid.configure do |config|
    config.connect_to("test_habtmexample")
  end
  Mongoid.purge!

  frank=Person.create(name:"Frank")
  joe=Person.create(name:"Joe")
  ccon = Appointment.create(name:"Comicon")
  aday = Appointment.create(name:"Arbor day")

  frank.appointments << ccon
  frank.appointments << aday
  ccon.persons << joe
  joe.reload
end

go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice gentleman on freenode helped me out. Those two evals can be replaced with:

```
obj= self.send(relationship.to_sym).find(did)
self.send(relationship.to_sym).delete(obj)
```